# Lion OS Remove Categorizing in Finder

Tags: finder

i just got my hands on lion after some years in previous mac versions. There is a feature in finder that i absolutely hate though. When i select Arrange By -> Date Modified, for instance, i get a categorized, incredibly inefficient view. Is it possible to get what i would normally get on leopard, just a list of last modified files, without the horrendous categories ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "clean up by" option, not the "arrange by" one.

Comment: :O i only see an arrange by option

Comment: Brain fart, my bad, check the answer out again